# Getting URL for Image stored in MySQL as a blob

Tags: php, mysql

My wife's family is big into jigsaw puzzles and I am using PHP and MySQL to build them a site so they can see what puzzles they already own. This should prevent issues of buying the same puzzle twice.

When someone adds a puzzle, I will get them to upload an image of the box art that will then be stored as a blob in the database. I have all the puzzles in the database appearing in a styled table and I am happy with how it looks, but there is one more piece of functionality that I would like to have.

The table displays the uploaded blob/image, and I use CSS to reduce it to thumbnail size - a future revision will show a true thumbnail to save data but that comes later, for now a CSS reduced blob/image is fine.

What I want to do is also have the thumbnail image be a link that can be clicked to open the image full size, but I don't know how to grab a URL from a blob stored in MySQL and hoping someone can help. What I currently have is below. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
$conn = new mysqli($configs->host, $configs->username, $configs->password, $configs->database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT puzzles.name, puzzles.photo, manufacturers.name as manufacturer, owners.name as owner FROM puzzles LEFT JOIN manufacturers ON puzzles.manufacturer = manufacturers.id LEFT JOIN owners ON puzzles.owner = owners.id ORDER BY puzzles.id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<?php
echo '<table id="puzzleTable">
<tr>
<th>Puzzle Name</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Owner</th>
<th>Puzzle Photo</th>
<th>Options</th>
</tr>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['manufacturer'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['owner'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='NEED BLOB IMAGE URL HERE'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['photo'])."'/></a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='#'>Edit</a> | <a href='#'>Delete</a></td>";
  }
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: To me it looks like you're trying to display the image as base64 string, and not a URL?? I would rather store your image files on your server, for example after inserting a new record into `puzzles`, you get the `LAST_INSERT_ID` (primary key ID of your record), and use that PK to name your image file on your server. Many content management systems like wordpress etc. also store image files on the server, not in the DB.

Comment: Create a file `image.php` that takes an `id` parameter (the id of the image in your DB). When called, get the image blob from your DB and output it using the correct mime-type (using [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

Comment: _"but I don't know how to grab a URL from a blob stored in MySQL"_ - but you are doing exactly that already, for the `src` of your `img` element ...

Comment: @CBroe That is true, but when I tried using it, the URL became: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAABt and a ton of gibberish, I assume the raw blob data.

Comment: Now _that_ is a security feature, https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/

Answer (score 0):

You should create a link to a php page. A parameter for the ID of the record related to the database should be sent to it. In the php page, set the header like this: `header("Content-type: imageType)`.

[mysql blob using php](https://phppot.com/php/mysql-blob-using-php/)

Answer (score -1):

for build your app that return your URL and you can show this image, you should to do a insert in your db with your local storage folder or internet URL. In new column. Blob return only object image, but I recommend you that not use blob, think that if your app it grows, you db will be very weight and will delay in return data.

you can to do:

**query for url internet**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO puzzles(column, column, column, url)
VALUES ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'https://urlInternet')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

*query for url local*

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO puzzles(column, column, column, url)
    VALUES ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', '/images/'.$_POST["img"])";
    
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

When you return your data:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['manufacturer'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['owner'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='".$row['URL']"'><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['photo'])."'/></a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='#'>Edit</a> | <a href='#'>Delete</a></td>";
  }
```

Comment: Saving the file on the disk creates many security issues. It also requires more coding to control data in the database and file management by the programmer.

Comment: @MostafaNZ it´s really, but if it´s app for his family and in local, i think that it´s most easy way. If he don´t want save in local, he can use internet URL i sayed before

Comment: @MostafaNZ "_Saving the file on the disk creates many security issues_" Like what?

Comment: @brombeer For example, users other than the database admin have access to the files. It is possible to delete or change the name of the file. while the record in the database is not changed.